# How much business logic/abstraction would typically be provided by an ESB

Tags: architecture, esb

I'm looking at a customer requirement which specifies an ESB (in little detail). I'm not a professional developer, I tend to fulfil a product owner type of role, but ESB is a term I've never really had to get to grips with before. Googling reveals that it's more of an architectural style than a specific component, providing various data transport and translation services to allow disparate applications to be loosely coupled.

I'd like to get some expert opinion on what an ESB might include. For example if I had a bunch of applications, many of which had some concept of receiving a 'command' from another application, but each with different protocol and content, might an ESB offer a generalised 'send command' method accessible using common syntax over a range of protocols? Essentially offering a high-level API across the applications? Might those methods include business logic (for example prioritising which commands get sent, rejecting commands based on current operational conditions etc?)

Would an ESB typically hold state information or is it more transient? For example if some applications report state periodically, might that be held in the bus for retrieval by other applications (or would that be regarded as a peristence application using the ESB)? I've read that ESBs often include a messagin capability so I's guess yes, but what I'm after here is what a typically dev or architect would regard as typical ESB functionality to give me a steer on how to interpret the requirement and what questions to ask when I speak with our own architect. Appreciate this is rather broad but hopefully enough to be considered an acceptable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a broad based question, I would like to provide you an overview and pick some of your questions from the content posted by you. Hope this info helps.

**What ESB might include?**

ESB allows business information to flow between disparate applications across multiple hardware and software platforms. ESB is more of a middleware layer which holds application connectivity logic and minimal to NO business logic. This allows applications to do what it does best without worrying about embedding any connectivity  logic on how to interact with other N number of applications that require the data from it. ESB architecture attempts to solve the point to point spaghetti mess in an enterprise.

Few of the many important functions of ESB are listed below:

```
Data transformation : For example, XML to JSON format or JSON to CSV format

Protocol transformation : For example, FTP to HTTPS 

Enrichment : Data passing through ESB layer could be enriched before delivery to destination

Routing : Based on payload or pre-determined rules, route data to appropriate destination
```

The below wiki page, gives a detailed description of ESB, including the origin of the name ESB.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus

**Would an ESB typically hold state information or is it more transient?**

Ideally, ESB shouldn't hold any state information. Specially, now when all ESB vendors are moving from monolithic ESB deployments to microservices based deployments. Enterprises have a separate messaging layer to temporarily queue data. Messaging allows decoupling of your applications. For example, when App A wants to talk to App B, App B has to be online. But if App A can drop messages in the messaging layer, then in this case App B needn't be waiting for the messages from App A. It can go pick data from the messaging layer as and when it is ready to do so at its own pace. This way both App A and App B are decoupled from each other. You can go through the following link on Message and Queuing => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queuing_service

You should probably start understanding, the current application landscape in the enterprise and how see how applications interact with each other. Since ESB is already mentioned in your post, have discussions on visibility of data through the integration layer(ESB being a component of it). For example, Suppose App A pushes data and App B complains of not receiving the data, from an end business user, how can he investigate before reaching out to the application support team. Also, you might want to understand the governance aspect of the ESB.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a VERY broad question here, and one that is fraught with opinions and best-practices which may not be held by your particular architect.  Any advice given here is doomed to be overly-broad an will generally just set you up for an argument with your architect.

You would be far better off having this conversation with your architect than with StackOverflow.  That disclaimer being made, read this article from [MuleSoft](https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/what-esb).  It gives a great overview of the general capabilities and purposes of an ESB.  This needs to be tempered with the fact that YOUR organization may be using it differently.  An ESB is a tool, and where it fits into your environment may not be where it fits into other organization's.

The things you are asking about CAN all be done with an ESB, whether they SHOULD be done depends on how your architects are designing the solution.  Go ahead and read this article, then have an open and honest conversation with your architect about how this technology is being used in your organization.